# How to match a URL containing emojis using a regex?

Tags: regex, url, unicode, emoji

How can I write a regular expression to match URLs that contain emojis? The regex should match ordinary alphanumeric URLs along with URLs containing emojis in the domain name, path and/or parameters such as:

```
http://.to
http://www..to/
http://.to/I❤️coding?ref=
```

Most web applications today (including, but not limited to, social networks, online communities, etc.) detect automatically URLs posted by the users as text and convert them into hyperlinks. Nonetheless, almost none of them (StackOverflow included) properly matches URLs that include emojis such as the examples reported above, which are valid, 100% working and which are becoming more and more popular.
For all these reasons, the current question is very relevant in terms of code implementation of more modern URL matching regular expressions using any programming language.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Unicode
…

Comment: You make it sound like it's a bad thing. It isn't. Emojis are cancer and URLs should always be plaintext visible.

Comment: @DanteTheSmith it's just a matter of time. Emojis in URLs are already visible in some modern browsers (check out Safari and Safari Mobile). Some people downvoted my question yet I think it is very relevant and we should not be so "radical" on this topic. Whether as developers we like it or not, URLs containing emojis have a number of advantages (e.g. advertisement and marketing campaigns) and we'll see more and more of them in future so we should deal with it.

Comment: I didn't downvote, the question has a right to be asked. I just stated an opinion. You would figure it's Safari who brings in cancer :) As for answer if you could get a complete list of all emoji codes, you can always try checking if a string contains substring from the list. Unless they all have some standard formats they come in a regex would not be of much use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regular expression matches ordinary alphanumeric URLs along with URLs containing emojis in the domain name, path and/or parameters:

```
https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,256}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9\u1F60-\uFFFF@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

Try it out here: https://regexr.com/3gsl9

Notice that the range of unicode characters that include emojis (i.e. \uXXXX-\uXXXX) might need to be updated in future when new emojis will be added.

Answer (score 0):

http://\S+

Where \S+ captures all non whitespace

The trick is keeping the regex from being too greedy, you may need some additional info to help determine the end of the url, is it whitespace or encapsulated in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Regex to check URL contains Alphabets

```
String alphabets= "(.*[a-zA-Z].*)";
```

Regex to check URL contains Numbers

```
String numbers= "(.*[0-9].*)";
```

Regex to check URL contains special characters

```
 String special = "(.*[!,@,$,%,^,&,*,#,~,`,{,},%,|,(,),-,_,=,+,[,],;,:,',\",,,<,.,>,/,?].*$)";
```

Regex to check URL contains alphanumeric and emojis

```
 String emo="^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&()-*/!+=])(?=\\S+$).{size,}$";
```

Adjust size and change the special characters as per your need.