# Validate URLs which contain emojis in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm validating URLs with the following method:

```
+ (BOOL)confirmValidUrl:(NSString *)url {

    BOOL isValidURL = NO;
    NSString *urlRegEx = @"(?:www\\.)?[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,3}(\\.\\w{2})?(/(?<=/)(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?)?";
    NSPredicate *urlPredic = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];
    isValidURL = [urlPredic evaluateWithObject:url];

    return isValidURL;
}
```

Now I need to mark as valid URLs the ones that have emojis like **http://.la** but I haven't found anything related to this, does someone know how I should modify my method to do what I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need a regex for this. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224726/3151675

Comment: Posible Solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/46547726/1280188

Comment: Thanks but none of these solutions are working

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use this:
e.x.http://www.xn--vi8hiv.ws/

```
+ (BOOL) urlIsValiad: (NSString *) url
{
    NSString *regex =
    @"((?:http|https)://)?(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{1,25}\\.)?[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,3}(\\.\\w{2})?(/(?<=/)(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?)?";
    NSPredicate *regextest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

   if ([regextest evaluateWithObject: url] == YES) {
       NSLog(@"URL is valid!");
   } else {
       NSLog(@"URL is not valid!");
   }
   return [regextest evaluateWithObject:url];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ketan Odedra, but I have tried this and still not working

Comment: can you show me which url are you using?

Comment: It's just below my code: http://.la

Comment: its same url " http://xn--ls8h.la/ " and it is valid.i checked it

Comment: Maybe it is working for you because you are turning emojis into text.
I'm trying with and without http, https, www, and your code is not working for me.